# How to click on a particular column in a list view android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, onclicklistener

this is my code:

```
adapter= new EditAdapter(getApplicationContext(),sectionTopic);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ListView li = this.getListView();
    li.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View myView, int position,
                long arg3) {

            TableLayout view = (TableLayout) myView ;
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

            itemName = name.getText().toString();



            Intent intent= new Intent(EditActivity.this, SectionDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", itemName);

            startActivityForResult(intent,1);

        }
    });
```

EditAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_edit, parent, false);

    if (position%2==1){
        vowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(170, 218, 203));
    }
    else{
        vowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(147, 213, 212));
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView budget = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.budget);
    TextView expense = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.expense);
    ImageView pic = (ImageView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.pic);

    budget.setText(String.format("%.2f",arrayList.get(position).getBudget()));
    name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
    expense.setText(String.format("%.2f",arrayList.get(position).getMaking()));

    AsyncDownloadImage image = new AsyncDownloadImage(pic);
    image.execute(arrayList.get(position).getPic());


    return vowView;
}
```

I have a ListView of a tableRow, that when you click on a row you move to another screen.
I want that in addition to that, when I press on a certain column (on the text view- "addBtn") it will move to a different screen.

How to click on a specific?

this is my list view table:

```
<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="#e0eee0" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/plus"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="2"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"

         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/expense"
        android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
        android:background="#e6e6fa"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="900"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:lines="2"
         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/budget"
        android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
        android:background="#ffe4e1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1000"
        android:lines="2"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
        android:background="#e0eee0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="מזון"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:lines="2" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: In general, you need to set on click to the `addBtn` inside the `getView(...)` method of your adapter. I can direct you exactly to the right place, but first update the question and add `EditAdapter` content. The important place is `public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

Answer (score 0):

For being able to move to other activity by clicking on certain `View` inside the row, you need to set `OnClickListener` to your view inside `getView` method.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_edit, parent, false);

    if (position%2==1){
        vowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(170, 218, 203));
    }
    else{
        vowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(147, 213, 212));
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView budget = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.budget);
    TextView expense = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.expense);
    ImageView pic = (ImageView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.pic);

    // ... here ->
    TextView button = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // open here other activity
        }
    });
    // <- ....

    budget.setText(String.format("%.2f",arrayList.get(position).getBudget()));
    name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
    expense.setText(String.format("%.2f",arrayList.get(position).getMaking()));

    AsyncDownloadImage image = new AsyncDownloadImage(pic);
    image.execute(arrayList.get(position).getPic());

    return vowView;
}
```

Comment: Once I added the code, nothing works. Only when I cancel the OnItemClickListener in the EditActivity, it works. But I need two of the options to work ..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [blog](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2011/08/clickable-zones-in-listview-items/), which is about clikable zones in listview items, this might be helpful.