# How to click on a particular View / ViewGroup of any row populated by ListView through JSON?

Tags: android, json, listview

I want to click on a particular view inside a list of listView items. Please see image for reference. [image: Please see this...]

I need to click on viewgroups which contains train class information (1A,2A,etc).
ex - I need to click on (CC,N) of second train in list view.

I have tried following questions.

[How to click on a particular column in a list view android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571174/how-to-click-on-a-particular-column-in-a-list-view-android)

[How to click on specific list view item child view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282209/how-to-click-on-specific-list-view-item-child-view)

**UPDATE: Code added**

In Oncreate()

```
trainList = new ArrayList<>();
new GetTrains().execute();
```

Here GetTrains() is the class extending AsyncTask for which below postexecute is shown.

This is the code in my post execute -

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        TextView totalFound = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalTrainFoundText);

        totalFound.setText(total+" Trains Found");

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                trainPopulate.this, trainList,
                R.layout.train_row, new String[]{"dtime", "atime",
                "tname","tnumber","tduration","1a","2a","3a","cc","sl","2s"}, new int[]{R.id.dep_time_train_row,
                R.id.arr_time_train_row, R.id.train_name_row, R.id.train_number_row, R.id.duration_train_row,
                R.id.class1Aavailability,R.id.class2Aavailability,R.id.class3Aavailability,R.id.classCCavailability,
                R.id.classSLavailability,R.id.class2Savailability});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }
        });


    }
```

If I apply onItemClickListener() then it will provide me the view of the row which is clicked(like 1st row, second row...) but what I need is the view of the particular View('cc' TextView) inside that clicked row and make an Intent to it.

Comment: You just need to assign an OnClick event handler to the child elements.

For example: If the element CC is a TextView, assign that TextView an OnClick event (CC.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(View v) {....}); And inside the OnClickListener, do what you want to do.

If your child views does not have an event listener, when you click them, the container will receive the event.

Comment: Its giving null pointer exception

Comment: I did this in onCreate after inflating ListView.

cc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),trainNumber.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

Here, train number is the train number of the corresponding row in which I clicked cc

Comment: can you post some code. most likely you're not getting the value in findViewById(R.id.childView)